# Graylog SMTP server without TLS/SSL

Tags: docker, graylog2, graylog

I want to start graylog with smtp support via docker. I do it like this:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 12201:12201/udp \
  -e GRAYLOG_NODE_ID=My_Node_Id \
  -e GRAYLOG_SMTP_SERVER="Server.name.local --no-tls --no-ssl --web-url=http://web.name.local" \
  -e GRAYLOG_SERVER_SECRET=Secret \
  -v /graylog/data:/var/opt/graylog/data \
  -v /graylog/logs:/var/log/graylog graylog2/allinone
```

Graylog is working fine except that I can't send an email test message (in Graylog: **Streams** - **Manage Alerts** - **Send test alert**). Doing so I get an error screen in the web interface

[image]

Removing

> --no-tls

from the docker configuration, I don't get that screen. But of course now I get an error message

> An error occurred while trying to send an email! (triggered 20 hours
>   ago) The Graylog server encountered an error while trying to send an
>   email.  This is the detailed error message:
>   org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException:  Sending the email to the
>   following server failed : Server.name.local:587 
>   (javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>   nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: P KIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:  unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target)

That error is ok as there is no tls/ssl support.

But why do I get an error screen in the web interface with --no-tls? Any ideas how I can send mails without ssl? Am I doing something wrong with docker? Did anyone succeed in using docker, graylog and email without tls/ssl?

In the image, one can read

> Please check that the servers shown to the right are running and
>   reachable.

The ip address below the upper right red bar is not reachable. I don't even know that ip address. Where is that ip address coming from? Do I need to change it? Why is this failing only when --no-tls is activated?

I am using the latest version one can get via docker.

```
$ docker pull graylog2/allinone
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from graylog2/allinone
e9c5e611068d: Already exists
c29de585b225: Already exists
0b3e3644d782: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
f9cf24c26853: Already exists
ff82d8c50b3d: Already exists
4136ecd1ecd2: Already exists
Digest: sha256:ec56d3678f072...
Status: Image is up to date for graylog2/allinone:latest
```

**UPDATE::**

On the [docker container site](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/allinone/) for **graylog2/allinone** I just read that it is deprecated and one should use [graylog2/server](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/server/). I'll give it a try.

I am lost. Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: See http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/faq.html#i-have-configured-an-smtp-server-or-an-output-with-tls-connection-and-receive-handshake-errors-what-should-i-do for a related FAQ item.

Comment: Hey joschi, thanks for your reply. But I do _not_ want to use tls/ssl. I think I somehow have to setup "no_auth" smpt server. I am currently trying to change the settings #transport_email_use_auth = true
#transport_email_use_tls = true
#transport_email_use_ssl = true to false...

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get [graylog2/server](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/server/) up and running and failing I returned back to [graylog2/allinone](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/allinone/) and finally succeeded to receive an email. It seems to be important to specify **ALL** needed parameters like this:

```
GRAYLOG_SMTP_SERVER="Server.name.local --port=25 --no-tls --no-ssl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it's working on my graylog server in Docker.

I'm using Docker image: `graylog/graylog:2.3.2-1`

> In docker-compose format, so these can just be used with a '-e' in a 'docker run' command to pass environment variables.

```
environment:
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_ENABLED=true
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_HOSTNAME=smtp.myemailserver.com
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_PORT=25
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_AUTH=false
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_TLS=false
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_SSL=false
  - GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL=noreply@mycompany.com
```

The documentation doesn't cover any of this stuff and just takes searching and trial/error. I **think** any normal graylog configuration (.conf) parameter can be passed as an environment variable in the container with GRAYLOG_ prepended.

Comment: I also had a problem sending email from dockerized Graylog. I was getting exception  `org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.myemailserver.com:587 (javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out)`.

I can confirm that setting graylog options 'transport_email_use_tls' and 'transport_email_use_ssl' to `false` solves the issue.